# Couldn't fix the error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I couldn't fix that. When it tries to assign answeredCorrectly to numberLabel, I get a runtime error. :(

```
var answeredCorrectly: Int? = 0
func endGame(){
    let lastViewLet = LastView()
    println("Count of correct answers: \(answeredCorrectly)")
    lastViewLet.numberLabel.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: answeredCorrectly)
    answeredCorrectly = 0
    performSegueWithIdentifier("toEnd", sender: nil)
}
```

LastView class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit



class LastView: ViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        numberLabel.text = "1"
    }


}
```

Comment: And where is the code of the function which gave you the error?

Comment: I just changed the code and forgot the func. I edited it now. @milo526

Comment: Try debugging. Try to see if either `lastViewLet` is nil or if `numberLabel` is nil.

Comment: Neither of them is nil. I added answeredCorrectly = 506 to endGame() func. And I also added a default value(not 0) to numberLabel using viewDidLoad in LastView's class. @milo526

Comment: Think about it: `let lastViewLet = LastView()` creates  *new* instance of LastView, not a reference to any existing view (controller) in your app.

Comment: Nothing changes. I only have an @IBOutlet, viewDidLoad() func.

Comment: @MartinR you should add that as an answer, because that is probably the root cause.  `numberLabel` is possibly `nil`

Comment: I added further code for more info. @MartinR

Answer (score 0):

Your `answeredCorrectly` var is given a type of optional int, yet you assign a value of 0 to it.  Are you sure that's what you want?  If it will always have a value, you could use `Int`.

If you are using an optional, you should use the `if let` construct to ensure you have a value:

```
if let answeredCorrectlyInt = answeredCorrectly as? Int {
    println("Count of correct answers: \(answeredCorrectlyInt)")
    lastViewLet.numberLabel.text = String(answeredCorrectlyInt)
}
```

Also, you are using `String(stringInterpolationSegment: answeredCorrectly)` when you can just use `String(answeredCorrectly)` and it will do the right thing.

Comment: You could even use `”\(answeredCorrectly)”`

Comment: It prints answeredCorrectlyInt to console before crash, but I still getting error. Also I got Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) I got it everytime even asking the topic.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the IBOutlet is not connected to actual UILabel in Interface Builder. There should be a little circle left from the  `@IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!`. If the circle is empty, the variable is not connected to the label. Make sure it is connected or try reconnecting it.

Also, are you actually *showing* the LastView view controller?

Comment: Nothing different. I can see the IBOutlet name in referencing outlets of label. Even so, I reconnected the label and outlet. But same output. :(